# Difference of digital (binary) option price under normal and log-normal assumption

Tags: binary-options

Here is the question asked in interview：

> What's is the difference of digital (binary) option price under normal and log-normal assumptions of spot?

I think the log normal has fatter right tail than normal. However digital option is not sensitive to the large spot, therefore the price of log normal will be smaller than normal.

I don't know if I got to the point, but I hope you can add something.

Comment: It's a vague question. One difference is the price of a binary put with strike 0 is 1/2 under normal assumption with constant vol and 0 under lognormal assumption.

Comment: @FridoRolloos I think so, the interviewer said forget the closed formula, then I think the only difference  between normal and lognormal are positive/non-positive and fat right tail.

Comment: In that case say something about the price of digital put with strike zero (which is the probability the spot is less than zero), and also say something about the right tail (large positive strikes). I don't think very much more can be said.

Comment: The interviewer probably means to compare digital price given both models are calibrated to ATM vanilla.

Comment: @user121416 then what's the answer？

Comment: @user6703592 Think whether the normal model will generate a positive skew or negative?

Comment: lognormal has right skew, then It should has high price than normal?